# For - laço de repetição

Tags: java

Olá, sou novo aqui e no mundo da programação. Gostaria de saber como fazer a última parte desse exercício, utilizando o For. Até agora fiz isso:

```
for(int i = 1; i<=100; i++) {
    if(i%2==0) {
        System.out.println(i+" é par");
    }else {
        System.out.println(i+" é ímpar");
    }

    if(i%3==0){
        System.out.println("é múltiplo de 3");
    }

    if(i%4==0) {
        System.out.println("múltiplo de 4");
    }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual é a questão especificamente ? O verificar se os números são primos ? O que já fez para esse efeito ? Onde ficou travado ? Não vejo nenhum código na pergunta referente a isso

Comment: Rapaz, eu queria saber primeiro como fazer aquele segundo for, dentro do if, dentro do outro for.

Comment: A minha sugestão é fazer cada coisa individualmente, e no fim juntar tudo, como se fosse colar peças. Assim aprende bem como faz cada parte. Neste sentido o próximo passo seria você fazer um código para verificar se um numero é primo. Depois se tiver sucesso, junta as duas partes, da forma correta.

Comment: Certo. Muito obrigado ✌

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A segunda parte do seu problema:

```
if (i % 5 == 0){
    for(int a = 0; a < i; a++){
        if(a % 5 == 0){
            System.out.println("O número " + a + "é multiplo de 5 e anterior a " + i);

        }
    }
}
```

Com relação a números primos, não entendi que número deve ser comparado.

Comment: O exercício quer saber se cada número a ser impresso é primo ou não.

Comment: Na verdade seria mais eficiente se fizesse `for(int a = 0; a < i;  a += 5)`.